# Two queries, one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

### The goal

Iterating between two queries within a single view.

### The problem

In my application there is a comparison list of a specific product. At the top of the page, there is details of this product as its name, min/max price, photo and some other details.

What I need is something like this:

```
@modelComparisonList List<MyApp.Models.Products>
@modelProduct MyApp.Models.Products

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Comparing " + modelProduct.name;
}

<h1>There is @modelProduct.quantity products to compare</h1>   

<table>
    @foreach (var item in modelComparisonList)
    {
        <tr>
            <p>@item.productName</p>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <p>@item.productPrice</p>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <p>@item.marketName</p>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Can you understand my case?

I don't know how to perform a solution to resolve this. Can someone give me an idea?

Comment: Side note: rename your `Products` class to `Product`

Comment: +1 for the question title.

Comment: @SOfanatic was just an example, but thanks for your hint — in the future I'll consider it.

Comment: @Renan you are a sick puppy ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just make a wrapper class that contains both, ie simply:

```
public class TheViewModel
{
    public List<MyApp.Models.Products> Item1 { get; set; }
    public MyApp.Models.Products Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: AMAZING! Simple and concise answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it by using a view model. View models are there to represent your data on the view. Your view model can be a "concatenation" from multiple models.

Below is a couple of tips as well regarding your classes and properties.

Your product domain model will look like this:

```
public class Product
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }

     public string MarketName { get; set; }

     public decimal Price { get; set; }

     // Other properties not mentioned above
}
```

Your view model could look something like this:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
     public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }

     public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Your action method could look something like this:

```
public ActionResult Compare(int id)
{
     ProductViewModel viewModel = new ProductViewModel
     {
          Product = productRepository.GetBuId(id),
          Products = productRepository.GetAll()
     };

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

And your view could look something like this:

```
@model YourProject.ViewModels.Products.ProductViewModel

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Comparing " + @Model.Product.Name;
}

<h1>There is @Model.Product.Quantity products to compare</h1>

<table>
     @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
     {
          <tr>
               <td>@product.Name</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td>@product.Price</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td>@product.MarketName</td>
          </tr>
     }
</table>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That is exactly what I did, Brendan. By the way, thanks about your contribution!